# gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file

Tags: dired, tramp

Linux Mint 20.1

Emacs 27.1

I connect to remote Linux host by tramp mode. Success connect. Nice.

But when in dired mode I try to open log file (press Enter) I get the next message:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
```

Same remote log file I success open by Midnight Commander.

P.S. When I copy this file from remote host to my local machine I success open it in dired mode.

Comment: Hard to say w/o further information. Pls write a Tramp bug report (see the manual).

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve a similar issue, where I am able to open some files but get your error message for others, by the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791019/1346276): turn off gzip compression by setting `tramp-inline-compress-start-size` to `nil`.